# Read from an input stream and create a certain instance from the data

Tags: java, oop, io, stream

I have a BaseProduct interface and two implementing classes, GroceryProduct and TechProduct. I created a method to read a product from an input stream of bytes. Considering that both products have similar fields, I was looking for a way to create a certain type of product with this method.

The only solution I came up with was creating a helper method getting constructor for the product class and creating an instance accordingly.

Is it the optimal solution for that problem? Is there another way to read a product from an input stream and create an instance of a certain Product type?

```
public static BaseProduct input(Class<? extends BaseProduct> productClass, InputStream in) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(in);
    String brand = dataInputStream.readUTF();
    String productName = dataInputStream.readUTF();
    BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(dataInputStream.readUTF());
    int totalQuantity = dataInputStream.readInt();
    int defectiveQuantity = dataInputStream.readInt();
    List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Review review : reviews) {
        String userName = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        int rating = dataInputStream.readInt();
    }
    return createProductInstance(brand, productName, price, totalQuantity, defectiveQuantity, reviews, productClass);
}

private static BaseProduct createProductInstance(String brand, String productName, BigDecimal price, int totalQuantity, int defectiveQuantity, List<Review> reviews, Class<? extends BaseProduct> productClass) {
    try {
        Constructor<? extends BaseProduct> productConstructor = productClass.getConstructor(String.class, String.class, BigDecimal.class, int.class, int.class, List.class);
        return productConstructor.newInstance(brand, productName, price, totalQuantity, defectiveQuantity, reviews);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create product instance: " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. Don't use reflection. Just use polymorphism:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ProductFactory<T extends BaseProduct> {
    T create(String brand, 
             String productName, 
             BigDecimal price, 
             int totalQuantity, 
             int defectiveQuantity, 
             List<Review> reviews);
}
```

And then pass an instance of such an interface, which can be written as a lamdbda:

```
public static <T> T input(ProductFactory<T> factory, InputStream in) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(in);
    String brand = dataInputStream.readUTF();
    String productName = dataInputStream.readUTF();
    BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(dataInputStream.readUTF());
    int totalQuantity = dataInputStream.readInt();
    int defectiveQuantity = dataInputStream.readInt();
    List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Review review : reviews) {
        String userName = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        int rating = dataInputStream.readInt();
    }
    return factory.create(brand, productName, price, totalQuantity, defectiveQuantity, review);
}
```

And call it like this, for example:

```
ProductFactory<GroceryProduct> factory = 
    (String brand, String productName, BigDecimal price, int totalQuantity, int defectiveQuantity, List<Review> reviews) -> 
        new GroceryProduct(brand, 
                           productName, 
                           price, 
                           totalQuantity, 
                           defectiveQuantity, 
                           reviews);
input(factory, inputStream);
```

Note that it would be much cleaner if you defined a class (let's say `ProductInformation`) to hold all these arguments, and you passed an instance of that class as argument to your product constructors. You could then replace the ProductFactory interface by a `Function<ProductInformation, T>`. Note however that, if you did that, you wouldn't even need that function anymore. You could just do

```
ProductInformation info = input(inputStream);
GroceryProduct product = new GroceryProduct(info);
```

Comment: What if I read from a file that contains `TechProduct` data? How is it possible to distinguish which product's `ProductInformation` I'm reading? It could be so that I'll create `GroceryProduct` out of the `ProductInformation` belonging to `TechProduct`.

Comment: You replace GroceryProduct by TechProduct.  Not sure I understand the question: you said the file contains the exact same information for both kinds of products, so you need to know what you're reading.

Comment: What if file contains information for both kinds of products or I don't know whos `ProductInformation` is in the file? The products have similar fields, but when reading the information I need to create an instance with data that belonged to it. For example, I do not want to create a `TechProduct` with a `productName` field "potatoes" )

Comment: Well, you need to have some info in the file telling what kind of product it is. Or you need to maintain a list of possible product names belonging to each category.